# How to Get div id at caret position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

How to get div id at caret position in jquery? for example my main div is main-box and mouse position is on `<div id="content"></div>`

```
<div id="main-box"> ........
 <div id="wrap" class="clearfix"> ............
 <div id="header"> ........
  <div id="content"> ...............
    <div id="section1"> ...... </div>
    <div id="section2"> ........ </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){  

 $('#main-box').click(function() { 
 alert(getCaretPosition(this));
});


  });
   function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
var caretPos = 0, containerEl = null, sel, range;
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
            caretPos = range.endOffset;
        }
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
        var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
        editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
        var tempRange = range.duplicate();
        tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
        tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
        caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
    }
  }
   return caretPos;
}

</script>
```

I need to get dive id when mouse over or click?
if someone has any idea please share!

Comment: if div is were your click event triggers on, then you can use  `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: If this code does not help, why showing it? You should rather try something then show your attempt ;)

Comment: in my div id main-box , over than 20 divs,but when I click on any part of body it return me only main-box

Comment: A little help : http://api.jquery.com/click/. Where is your own code?

Comment: Where is your javascript? :D

Comment: So there is no method to get current caret position div id?

Comment: There are plenty of results in google ("get caret position editable div"), but nothing absolutely reliable at first glance. Here is an example of what you can find : http://forrst.com/posts/Tracking_the_caret_position_in_a_contenteditable-P4l. I'm afraid you'll have to cross-browser check by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verry easy, http://jsfiddle.net/Ncnq6/1/

Attach the event listener on the document for all div elements. You can replace "mouseenter" by any other handler. `$(document).on("mouseover","div",function(e){`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like

```
$(e.currentTarget).attr('id)
```

inside your event function

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
alert($('.YourClass').attr('id'));
```

Good luck..

Comment: in my div id main-box , over than 20 divs,but when I click on any part of body it return me only main-box